# 404 Not Found when use request.urlretrieve

Tags: python, urllib, urlretrieve

I get some response from external service. Then need to get url from this response and by this url download a file.

When i pass url to urlretrieve from response.text, urlretrieve return an Error.

But when i manually copy the url. Then set variable in python. url = 'https://My_service_site.com/9a57v4db5_2023-02-14.csv.gz'.
urlretrieve works fine and download the file to computer by this link.

```
response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
#method 1 - get error
url = response.text[17:-2] #get the link like 'https://my_provide_name.com/csv_exports/5704d5.csv.gz'
urlrtv = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=url, filename='C:\\Users\\UserName\\Downloads\\test4.csv.gz')
>>return error: HTTP Error 404 Not Found

#method 2 - works fine
url2 = 'https://my_provide_name.com/csv_exports/5704d5.csv.gz'
urlrtv=urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=url2, filename='C:\\Users\\UserName\\Downloads\\test4.csv.gz')
>>works fine
```

When i copy url from method 1 and put in browser. It works fine.

**Edit:**
To be more precise i have tried to get url not like that response.text[17:-2]. Insted use json.loads to parse url from response. But still got the error

```
a = json.loads(response.text) 
>>{'csv_file_url': 'https://service_name.com/csv_exports/746d6.csv.gz'}
url = a['csv_file_url']
print(url)
>>https://service_name.com/csv_exports/746d6.csv.gz
```

**Solved:** Just add time.sleep(3) before downloading file.

```
url = response.json()['csv_file_url']
time.sleep(3)
urlrtv = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=url, filename=f'{storage_path}{filename}')
```

Comment: are you sure `response.text[17:-2]` is  `'https://my_provide_name.com/csv_exports/5704d5.csv.gz'` ?

Comment: I have tried to print each character from url and url2 varialbes, their type also. And they seems like identically.
h  --  h     <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
t  --  t     <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
t  --  t     <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
p  --  p     <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
...       ....
.  --  .     <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
z  --  z     <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>

Comment: Yes, I also guess maybe it's some hidden simbols in response.text[17:-2] or some strange data types. Binary or smth. But don't know how to check it.

Comment: I just have tried to use json.loads to be more precise.
a = json.loads(response.text) #{'csv_file_url': 'https://service_name.com/csv_exports/746d6.csv.gz'}
url = a['csv_file_url']
url        #https://service_name.com/csv_exports/746d6.csv.gz
Still the same error